# How to Retain the latest record and delete the older one using C# Interop

Tags: c#, interop, xls

I have an xls file with four columns

```
ID          Name           Date       File
1           charlie        01/09/2011 1.txt
2           charlie        12/25/2005 2.txt
3           nero           11/11/2011 3.txt
4           charlie        12/09/2011 4.txt
```

the process will be able to delete the older records of charlie and keep latest one
based on Name and Date other to columns are ignored.

expected xls will have following records

```
ID          Name           Date       File
3           nero           11/11/2011 3.txt
4           charlie        12/09/2011 4.txt
```

in this example the date in MM/DD/YYYY.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would need to group by the name, and take the recent date for each grouping, then select only the `ID` from the result.  `SELECT Table1.ID, MAX(Table1.Date) FROM Table1 GROUP BY Table1.Name`. So after you get this query then just use the `ID` field.

Next do a delete query (Psuedo Code) `DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE [Table].ID NOT IN (result from above)`

The following is done with LINQ to SQL:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var query = db.Table1s.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .Select(x => new
                                 {
                                     ID = x.Max(t => t.ID),
                                     Name = x.Max(t => t.Name),
                                     Date = x.Max(t => t.Date)

                                 });

            foreach (var n in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.ID + " " + n.Name + " " + n.Date);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            //Result:
            //4 charlie 12/9/2011
            //3 nero 11/11/2011

            var deleteQuery = db.Table1s.Where(x => !query.Select(t=> t.ID)
                                        .Contains(x.ID));

            db.Table1s.DeleteAllOnSubmit(deleteQuery);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            var testDeletion = db.Table1s;

            foreach (var n in testDeletion)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.ID + " " + n.Name + " " + n.Date);   
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is done against a database, but the basic logic still applies to an excel file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure you want this as an external program using c# with COM Interop to Excel, you might find some useful info on macros here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010014111.aspx

Otherwise you'll need to create a new C# project in visual studio and add references to Microsoft.Office.Core and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Once that's done, you could do something like the following (Note: you'll want better error cleanup):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelInterop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            try
            {
                FileInfo fiSource = new FileInfo(args[0]);
                FileInfo fiDest = new FileInfo(args[1]);
                Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fiSource.FullName,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];

                Dictionary<string, DateTime> hashNewest = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
                for (int iRow = 1; iRow < (double)sheet.Cells.Height; ++iRow )
                {
                    object oID = sheet.get_Range("A" + (iRow + 1), Type.Missing).get_Value(Type.Missing);
                    if (oID == null || oID.ToString().Trim().Length <= 0)
                        break;

                    object oName = sheet.get_Range("B" + (iRow + 1), Type.Missing).get_Value(Type.Missing);
                    string strName = "" + oName;
                    object oDate = sheet.get_Range("C" + (iRow + 1), Type.Missing).get_Value(Type.Missing);
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(oDate);
                    if( !hashNewest.ContainsKey(strName) )
                        hashNewest.Add(strName, dt);
                    else if (hashNewest[strName].CompareTo(dt) < 0)
                        hashNewest[strName] = dt;
                }

                for (int iRow = 1; iRow < (double)sheet.Cells.Height; ++iRow)
                {
                    object oID = sheet.get_Range("A" + (iRow + 1), Type.Missing).get_Value(Type.Missing);
                    if (oID == null || oID.ToString().Trim().Length <= 0)
                        break;

                    object oName = sheet.get_Range("B" + (iRow + 1), Type.Missing).get_Value(Type.Missing);
                    string strName = "" + oName;
                    object oDate = sheet.get_Range("C" + (iRow + 1), Type.Missing).get_Value(Type.Missing);
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(oDate);
                    if (!hashNewest[strName].Equals(dt))
                    {
                        sheet.get_Range(
                            string.Format("A{0}:D{0}", iRow+1),
                            Type.Missing
                            ).Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
                        --iRow;
                    }
                }

                File.Delete(fiDest.FullName);
                wb.SaveAs(fiDest.FullName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing );

                wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
            finally
            {
                app.Workbooks.Close();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```